# Method like getView() for GridLayout (not GridView)

Tags: android, out-of-memory, grid-layout

For an App I am working on, I have a GridLayout that I populate dynamically. It works great except for one thing. Right now, I'm simply loading all the images I want to display at once. However, the number of images I have to load can vary, meaning there is a risk of an OutOfMemoryException. What I need is a method like getView() in GridView, only then for GridLayout. I have been thinking about this a while now, but I'm still stuck. Does anybody have suggestions for an approach?

Answer (score 0):

`GridLayout` is used for aligning items in a grid. This is similar to grid systems in desings. `GridLayout` cannot work with adapters, which is what `GridView` is for.

Comment: I know that it can't work with adapters. I just want to create a similar system to an adapter myself.

Comment: You could extend an `AdapterView` and provide you own way of laying out items. That part is easy. It gets complex when you want to look for click events and trigger them. It gets more complex with accessibility related focus navigation.